# Build dependency issue with Grails and Maven

Tags: grails, maven, dependency-management, google-code, json-rpc

I'm trying to integrate Google's JSON RPC library in my Grails project. The Maven configuration is [here](http://code.google.com/p/json-rpc/wiki/Usage#Dependencies), I also took the snippet from the site...

```
<dependencies>
   <dependency>
      <groupId>org.json.rpc</groupId>
      <artifactId>jsonrpc</artifactId>
      <version>1.0</version>
   </dependency>
</dependencies>

<repositories>
   <repository>
      <id>json-rpc</id>
      <url>http://json-rpc.googlecode.com/svn/mavenrepo</url>
   </repository>
</repositories>
```

So, I took the above Maven config and placed it in my project's `BuildConfig.groovy`..

```
grails.project.dependency.resolution = {
  repositories{
    mavenRepo "http://json-rpc.googlecode.com/svn/mavenrepo"
  }

  dependencies {
    compile "org.json.rpc:jsonrpc:1.0"
  }
}
```

When I refresh project dependencies, Grails throws this error..

> org.json.rpc#jsonrpc;1.0: java.text.ParseException: inconsistent
>   module descriptor file found in
>   'http://json-rpc.googlecode.com/svn/mavenrepo/org/json/rpc/jsonrpc/1.0/jsonrpc-1.0.pom':
>   bad revision: expected='1.0' found='1.0-SNAPSHOT';

I'm not sure if this is a problem with the Google repo or with my config. Based on the error message it appears that Grails was expecting `1.0-SNAPSHOT` from the pom, so I change my build file to `compile "org.json.rpc:jsonrpc:1.0-SNAPSHOT"`, but that results in a "module not found" error message.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like the pom file from the repository has issues:

```
<groupId>org.json.rpc</groupId>
    <artifactId>jsonrpc</artifactId>
    <name>JSON-RPC</name>
    <version>${jsonrpc.version}</version>

    <properties>
        <jsonrpc.version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</jsonrpc.version>
        <java.version>1.5</java.version>

        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>
```

The artifact is version 1.0 but the version from the pom file is defined as 1.0-SNAPSHOT.

Comment: How about I download the JAR and pom, update the pom, create my own local repo, and just point to that? At least I can get around this problem for now if nobody on the project end will fix it

Comment: @RaffiM you could do that or just download the jar and put it in your `lib` directory until they resolve the pom issues.